# Set color per point 3d plot numpy/scipy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a set of data points from a kinect in the form of [x,y,z,r,g,b] and I want to plot [x,y,z] setting the point to [r,g,b]. The only thing I've been able to accomplish so far is to change the color per row as plot requires a distribution as far as I can tell.

This is my code so far:

```
i = 0
for frame in data[0]:
    fig = figure()
    ax2 = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    for col in frame:
        color_value=(median(col[:,3])/255, median(col[:,4])/255, median(col[:,5])/255)
        ax2.scatter(col[:,0],col[:,2]*(-1),col[:,1],color=color_value, alpha=0.25 )
    print(str(i))
    i += 1

    savefig(working_dir + 'images/scatter_point' + str(i) + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to HYRY for the suggestion of using scatter. It works, however one would need more RAM than I have for it to work practically in a 640x480 image. For future reference for anyone looking for this type of thing, the operative line is:

```
    ax2.scatter(frame[i][j][0], frame[i][j][2]*(-1), frame[i][j][1], color = (frame[i][j][3]/255, frame[i][j][4]/255, frame[i][j][5]/255), marker = 's', s=0.25)
```

`marker= 's'` means to use a square instead of a dot, `s=0.25` sets the dot smaller.

If you want to do a lower resolution image, restrict the for loop to only plot every other or every fourth point.

Comment: You should have a look at [this libfreenect example](https://github.com/amiller/libfreenect-goodies), which uses OpenGL to draw it, which will be much faster.

Comment: @IvoFlipse I tried to get that working but to no avail. Too many links in the chain to break I think. Do I actually need a kinect to get the demos working? I just have the dataset. Any other tips on getting OpenGL working for this application would be welcome, especially for Python3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `c` argument of `scatter` can receive a array of shape (N, 3) with values between 0 to 1 which represent color in RGB:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = np.random.sample(20)
y = np.random.sample(20)
z = np.random.sample(20)
c = np.random.rand(20, 3)
s = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c)

plt.show()
```

here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This does work but as the image is 640x480 it takes forever and my computer generally runs out of memory before it can actually render the whole graph. If I only plot every other point, it can crank out at least one graph before it locks up. Unfortunately, this use case doesn't seem to have been considered for numpy.